# How to implement social network timeline: Optimize data storage for reads or writes?

Tags: database-design, social-networking

What could be the most efficient way to implement twitter or facebook concept of timeline?

There are two ways that I can think off:

When a user writes an update it gets stored on a database for each follower / friend "mailbox". This makes user timeline reads really easy To implement but makes writes very expensive. Imagine a facebook page or user with millions of followers. That would mean millions of writes for each update, ouch!

The other alternative is to write only once on each new message and make the followers have to go over the database and return the latest updates from each user they are following. If you are sharding the data that might mean get updates from all servers in the cluster. This makes each read very expensive.

How would you go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Only an active person posts. Only active followers need posts.

Also, you can cache: just send updates. A person has for each active follower posts seen by that follower. Active followers need deleted, changed or new posts. That is more info recorded but less traffic per post.

A shard needs relevant info for the (active and inactive) people it serves.

You cannot do less work than getting updates to active followers and their shards.

Facebook doesn't show all of friends' posts. They send some posts of some friends. By having friends not be followers they reduce the work vs friends as follower. So if you can change the spec you can cheat your way out of work. Eg allow delaying showing updates until a time of less DBMS work and/or traffic.